# The encrypted sample was not found when using the PadBuster to padding oracle

Tags: asp.net, padding-oracle-attack

Though the PadBuster is a great tool in padding oracle,but when I attempt to decrypt the viewstate or the cookies in asp.net apps, it all tell me that The encrypted sample was not found.

Something may be wrong when I using it, but there is not so much information to tell me how to use it.

Does anyone has the experience about using the padbuster?

Can you show it to me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you asked the authors of the paper? (http://netifera.com/research/) They said they will publish more details about the ASP NET vulnerability. What you need is an encrypted sample that you can find in the website looking for WebResource.axd?d=(this) or ScriptResrouce?d=(this) or may be an encrypted viewstate (if it starts with weP is not encrypted)

Comment: thanks for your answer. what I want is only a demo to encrypt viewstate or cookies in asp.net. I have browsered the http://netifera.com/research . They only offer a demo for JSF.No more info about asp.net for a long time. Maybe they worried about the risk.

Answer (score 1):

It only works for the values, not cookies and viewstates.

There are now a few blogs that demonstrate the usage.

Search for something like, `MS10-070 exploit padbuster.pl`.